# C# HttpClient add header to allow duplicate record insert in Salesforce using salesforce Api

Tags: c#, salesforce, httpclient

While using Salesforce Api to push data from C# to Salesforce objects, I got stuck for Contacts object not pushing data as it was already available in Contacts object.
So there are two possibilities to cope with this.

- Either use the existing Contact's object record id.
- Or Allow duplicate record to be created in Contacts object.

> On Salesforce you get a popup to create new or use existing one, but how you can know about duplication using Api.

After exploring more on Salesforce Api documentation, I found the following link to implement allow duplicates via Api.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_duplicaterules.htm

Now the question is how can I Include this header in HttpClient request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question, I tried

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header", "allowSave=true;includeRecordDetails=false;");
```

It did not work, but the following line worked.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header", "allowSave=true");
```

It saved the duplicate Contacts Object record in Salesforce.